# Random values are going weird in conditional statement with seed

Tags: python, random, random-seed

```
from random import seed,random
for i in range(21):
     if i%3==0:
         seed(10)
     if i%2==0:
         random()
     else:
         random()
```

with above code, result is

```
0.5714025946899135
0.4288890546751146
0.5780913011344704
0.5714025946899135
0.4288890546751146
0.5780913011344704
0.5714025946899135
0.4288890546751146
0.5780913011344704
0.5714025946899135
0.4288890546751146
0.5780913011344704
0.5714025946899135
0.4288890546751146
0.5780913011344704
0.5714025946899135
0.4288890546751146
0.5780913011344704
0.5714025946899135
0.4288890546751146
0.5780913011344704
```

which,

```
a=0.5714025946899135
b=0.4288890546751146
c=0.5780913011344704
```

is continuously repeating.

But according to **seed(10)**, i should get only **`a=0.5714025946899135`** with a seed applyed,

and the others should be random.

but why other value (`0.4288890546751146` and
`0.5780913011344704`) is constant too?

Comment: According to the documentation of the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/random.html) module it generates pseudo-random numbers. It uses a [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) as the core generator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`seed(10)` sets the seed and resets the random number generator for that seed. So every 3rd iteration, you're just starting the random numbers (for seed = 10) back to the beginning. If you want different numbers, you need to set the seed to something else (ideally a random number, or leave blank which achieves this last option)

Put it another way, the random numbers that come out of random are deterministic. Given a seed, the output of the random function will be random when looked at as a series, but one that is pre-determined. Every time you pull numbers from a given seed, you'll get the exact same, random numbers, in the same sequence.